# Selenium C# try/catch assistance please

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

I am trying to write a try/catch in Selenium C# where if a web element is NOT present, catch the NoSuchElementException and if the element IS present, throw a custom exception.  Pretty green at coding so all help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
try
        {
          IWebElement spIcon = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#gridview-1080-record-2658335 > td.x-grid-cell.x-grid-td.x-grid-cell-headerId-propertiesColInv.wrappable.icon-spacer.x-unselectable.wrappable.icon-spacer > div > i"));
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException spIcoNotDisplayed)
        {
            //if spIcon is NOT present; 
            //then continue;
            //else throw custom exception 
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to throw a custom exception when the icon is present? And how would it get into the error handler in that case? Surely if the Icon is present, FindElement works and doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: Why don't you catch all exceptions and then do some sort of `if (ex is NoSuchElementException){ //Continue;}else{throw ex;}`

Answer (score 1):

```
var elementPresent = true;
try {
    IWebElement spIcon = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#gridview-1080-record-2658335 > td.x-grid-cell.x-grid-td.x-grid-cell-headerId-propertiesColInv.wrappable.icon-spacer.x-unselectable.wrappable.icon-spacer > div > i"));
}
catch (NoSuchElementException spIconNotDisplayed) {
    elementPresent = false;
}

if (elementPresent) {
    throw new ElementPresentException("The spIcon was found");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm not sure if this is what you want because what you are asking in text is different than your code. This code catches all exceptions and, if the exception is a `NoSuchElementException` it keeps the program going. Else you throw the catched exception or your custom exception.

```
try
{
    IWebElement spIcon = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#gridview-1080-record-2658335 > td.x-grid-cell.x-grid-td.x-grid-cell-headerId-propertiesColInv.wrappable.icon-spacer.x-unselectable.wrappable.icon-spacer > div > i"));
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Catches every exception
    if(ex is NoSuchElementException)
    {
        //Do nothing, if there's no icon your code will continue as if nothing happened
        //Or throw a custom exception for this case
    }
    else
    {
        //If there's an icon throw the exception
        //Here you can throw a custom exception
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both suggestions are exactly what I needed! thank you all so much!